# Tic Tac Cover up!! Can't get the program to work correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a Tic Tac Toe program, but it has a certain twist to it...you are able to cover up an opponent's `x` or `o` with a larger `x` or `o`. You have medium pieces and large pieces. For some reason, I can't get my board to display the current moves and it doesn't seem to recognize winning conditions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Winner checker.

def player_done(playerSym, board):
    return ((board[6] == playerSym and board[7] == playerSym and board[8] == playerSym) or # across the top
    (board[3] == playerSym and board[4] == playerSym and board[5] == playerSym) or # across the middle
    (board[0] == playerSym and board[1] == playerSym and board[2] == playerSym) or # across the bottom
    (board[6] == playerSym and board[3] == playerSym and board[0] == playerSym) or # down the left side
    (board[7] == playerSym and board[4] == playerSym and board[3] == playerSym) or # down the middle
    (board[8] == playerSym and board[5] == playerSym and board[2] == playerSym) or # down the right side
    (board[6] == playerSym and board[4] == playerSym and board[2] == playerSym) or # diagonal
    (board[8] == playerSym and board[4] == playerSym and board[0] == playerSym)) # diagonal

def opponent_done(oppSym, board):
    return ((board[6] == oppSym and board[7] == oppSym and board[8] == oppSym) or # across the top
    (board[3] == oppSym and board[4] == oppSym and board[5] == oppSym) or # across the middle
    (board[0] == oppSym and board[1] == oppSym and board[2] == oppSym) or # across the bottom
    (board[6] == oppSym and board[3] == oppSym and board[0] == oppSym) or # down the left side
    (board[7] == oppSym and board[4] == oppSym and board[1] == oppSym) or # down the middle
    (board[8] == oppSym and board[5] == oppSym and board[2] == oppSym) or # down the right side
    (board[6] == oppSym and board[4] == oppSym and board[2] == oppSym) or # diagonal
    (board[8] == oppSym and board[4] == oppSym and board[0] == oppSym)) # diagonal

# Sets up the Board

def drawBoard(board):
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[6] + ' | ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[3])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[0] + ' | ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2])
    print('   |   |')

#Prints the current board

def print_board(board):
    # Make a duplicate of the board list and return it the duplicate.
    dupeBoard = []
    for i in board:
        dupeBoard.append(i)
    return dupeBoard

#The Board

board = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

done = False

#The Move list for X's and O's

xmovesList = ["*","x","X"]
omovesList = [".","o","O"]

#Greeting message and choosing the initial X and O assignment.
print "Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe-Cover-Up!"
playerSym = raw_input("Player 1, please select either X or O for your pieces: ")
print

#Player and opponent move assignment
if (playerSym == "X"):
    playerSym = xmovesList
    oppSym = omovesList
    turn = "X"
else:
    playerSym = omovesList
    oppSym = xmovesList
    turn = "O"

#Main game loop.
while not done:
    drawBoard(board)


    print turn,"'s turn"
    if (turn == "X"):
        player = xmovesList
        opponent = omovesList
    else:
        player = omovesList
        opponent = xmovesList

    print "Select the place you want to play (0-8)"
    print_board(board)

    pos = input("Select: ")
    if pos <=8 and pos >=0:
        Y = pos/3
        X = pos%3
        if X != -1:
            X -=1
        else:
            X = 2
            Y -=1

        if board == " ":
            board = player[9]
            moved = True
            done = player()
        elif board != " ":
            if board == opponent[0]:
                board = player[1]
                moved = True
                done = player_done()
                done = opponent_done()
            if board == opponent[1]:
                board = player[2]
                moved = True
                done = player_done()
                done = opponent_done()

        if done == False:
            if turn == "X":
                turn = "O"
            else:
                turn = "X"
```

Comment: Your (redundant) definitions of `check_done1` don't match the invocations later on.  Does this program even run without any errors?  Oh, wait, the invocations are for `check_done`, without the `1`.  Definitely an error waiting to happen.

Comment: You cannot define two functions named `check_done1()`; the second overwrites the first. Moreover, you don't show the definition of `check_done()` (no number), which is what you call later on.

Comment: well i just renamed them and changed them down in the elif and if statments... still doesn't fix anything...

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the program not actually recording them into the board... because if you play the game it doesn't actually update it with any symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were mltiple issues with it.
For emptiness You were comparing with " " where as you are initialing board with 1-9
Also major issue of error :

```
board = player[9]
```

This you needed

```
board[pos] = player[0]
```

Also you need to fix checking logic to :

```
board[6] in playerSym  # and not board[6] == playerSym
```

This is program with some fixes.

```
#Winner checker.

def check_done(playerSym,board):
    return ((board[6] in playerSym and board[7] in playerSym and board[8] in playerSym) or # across the top
    (board[3] in playerSym and board[4] in playerSym and board[5] in playerSym) or # across the middle
    (board[0] in playerSym and board[1] in playerSym and board[2] in playerSym) or # across the bottom
    (board[6] in playerSym and board[3] in playerSym and board[0] in playerSym) or # down the left side
    (board[7] in playerSym and board[4] in playerSym and board[3] in playerSym) or # down the middle
    (board[8] in playerSym and board[5] in playerSym and board[2] in playerSym) or # down the right side
    (board[6] in playerSym and board[4] in playerSym and board[2] in playerSym) or # diagonal
    (board[8] in playerSym and board[4] in playerSym and board[0] in playerSym)) # diagonal


# Sets up the Board

def drawBoard(board):
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[6] + ' | ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[3])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[0] + ' | ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2])
    print('   |   |')

#Verifies if board is not full with all largest signs and no mpre moves are possible.
def movesPossible(board):
    #TODO: implement this
    return True

#Prints the current board

def print_board(board):
    # Make a duplicate of the board list and return it the duplicate.
    dupeBoard = []
    for i in board:
        dupeBoard.append(i)
    return dupeBoard

#The Board

board = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

done = False

#The Move list for X's and O's

xmovesList = ["*","x","X"]
omovesList = [".","o","O"]

#Greeting message and choosing the initial X and O assignment.
print "Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe-Cover-Up!"
playerSym = raw_input("Player 1, please select either X or O for your pieces: ")
print

#Player and opponent move assignment
if (playerSym == "X"):
    player = xmovesList
    opponent = omovesList
else:
    player = omovesList
    opponent = xmovesList

drawBoard(board)

#Main game loop.
while movesPossible(board):
    print player[2],"'s turn"
    print "Select the place you want to play (0-8)"
    print_board(board)
    moved = False
    pos = input("Select: ")
    if pos <=8 and pos >=0:
        Y = pos/3
        X = pos%3
        if X != -1:
            X -=1
        else:
            X = 2
            Y -=1

        if board[pos] == str(pos):
            board[pos] = player[0]
            moved = True
            done = check_done(player,board)
        else :
            if board[pos] == opponent[0]:
                board[pos] = player[1]
                moved = True
                done = check_done(player,board)
            if board[pos] == opponent[1]:
                board[pos] = player[2]
                moved = True
                done = check_done(player,board)
    drawBoard(board)
    if done:
        break;
    if moved :
        player,opponent = opponent,player

if(done):
    print player[2], "wins "
else:
    print "No more moves possible. It's a draw."
```